# Error while creating conda environment in python 3.7, only supports python 3.10

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, conda, dependency-management, miniconda

I have miniconda installed on my macbook pro M1. I want to create a conda environment with python version 3.7. I tried running following commands, but it's throwing an error and I'm not able to install python 3.7. Do I need to install anaconda instead of miniconda here?

Commands I have tried

```
conda install python=3.7 -c conda-forge
```

and

```
conda create -n myenv python=3.7 -c conda-forge
```

I also tried running the same command without `-c conda forge` parameter, but the same error is getting thrown.

Output of the command above:

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - python=3.7

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/osx-arm64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-arm64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-arm64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```